# How to write response on IP address in TCP/IP socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have written a simple server to accept TCP connections and to read data from clients.

My question is: I have multiple clients with different IP addresses sending data on the same port. How can I write data to only one specific client by using its IP address?

Comment: Check out the `select` system call and it's related macros to find the file descriptor in question, namely `FD_SET` and `FD_ISSET` and others.

Comment: Multiple clients can have the *same* IP address, so using the IP address to distinguish them is not going to work. You need to at least use IP:port.

Comment: how can i get the IP:port. I am new to socket programming i don't know the file descriptors method for it. can you recommend some good examples or tutorials for it.

Comment: If you don't know the file descriptor for the socket you have something wrong with your code that you need to fix. You need it to send to that client. You can get the IP:port via `getpeername().`

Comment: I   am doing it in java and using buffers , will i need to use file descriptors?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have the file descriptors for the connected TCP sockets. It is easy to retrieve the addresses of the remote hosts.

The key is the getpeername() system call, which allows you to find out the address of the remote end of a socket.

Comment: how can i get the IP. I am new to socket programming i don't know the file descriptors method for it. can you recommend some good examples or tutorials for it.

Comment: The fd you can out of a connect(client side)/accept (server side) is the FD you must be looking for take a look @ the example below:
http://alas.matf.bg.ac.rs/manuals/lspe/snode=48.html
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSB23S_1.1.0.11/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.11/gtpc2/cpp_getpeername.html?cp=SSB23S_1.1.0.11%2F0-3-8-1-0-6-10

Comment: if i am able to get file IP:port using file descriptor then how can i write to that client IP:port?

Comment: if i am able to get file IP:port using file descriptor then how can i write to that client IP:port? and i am using buffers for reading and writing data in java.

Comment: Just take a look @ example:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html